# what are the use cases of existentials in Scala if there is subtyping?

Tags: scala, haskell, existential-type, subtyping

Is there any meaningful reason why existentials exist in Scala if Scala has also subtyping?

For example in Haskell existentials can be used for heterogenous [lists](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections) but in Scala heterogeneous lists can be created just by using subtyping.

This makes me wonder why would anyone ever want to use existentials if there is subtyping in Scala ? Is there any use case for existentials that cannot be more conviniently solved by subtyping ? I am not sure there is. Any counterexamples ?

EDIT: Existentials are useful for defining higher kinded types (Functor, Monad, etc), that I understand, but besides them, is there any other meaningful use case ?

Comment: Existentials help when interfacing with Java wildcards and raw types: http://typelevel.org/blog/2015/02/26/rawtypes.html See also the section on existential types of this interview: http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/scalas_type_system.html

Comment: many thanks ! that explains a lot !

Comment: Out of curiosity, doesn't something like Coyoneda work far better with existentials?

Answer (score 3):

Example of existentials from my working project:

Implementing type safe parameter storage

```
trait Parameter[T] // T is a type of a value related to this parameter

trait ParameterStorage {
   def getValue[T](p: Parameter[T]): Option[T]
}

//implementation
type ParamAndValue = (Parameter[T], T) forSome { type T; }

//initialize storage with pairs of parameters and values
class StorageImpl(pairs: ParamAndValue*) { 
   ...
}
```

Comment: interesting, how does this solution compare to f bounded polymorphism ? wouldn't that be another way of doing the same ?

Comment: I haven't seen examples of F-bounded polymorphism that I liked. Googlable examples about Ordering violate separation of concerns. Of course existentials is not a killer feature since Martin Odersky removed it in Dotty. I think it can be emulated with typeclasses.

Answer (score 2):

Consider e.g. `Array[_]`. It isn't at all the same as `Array[Any]`, e.g.

```
val x: Array[Any] = new Array[Any](5)
x(0) = "" // legal
val y: Array[_] = new Array[Double](5)
y(0) = "" // illegal
```

> EDIT: Existentials are useful for defining higher kinded types (Functor, Monad, etc), that I understand, but besides them, is there any other meaningful use case ?

No. `F[_]` in `Functor[F[_]]` *looks* the same as an existential, but isn't one at all.

Comment: hmmm.... i dont even get this.... how does this even work ? why does the second not compile ? what is the type of `y` ? isn't this a compiler bug ?

Comment: 1. Because you can't put a `String` into an `Array` of unknown type. 2. The type of `y` is `Array[_]`, as it says. 3. Of course it isn't a compiler bug, why would you think so?

Comment: So if the type of y is `Array[_]` then how is it possible to assign to it an `Array` of `Double`s ? How is `Array[_]` even useful ? I noticed already two compiler bugs in the last few daysa as I was experimenting with existentials.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that came up just right now:

```
object Test{
  trait Entity
  case class SEntity() extends Entity
  case class RefVal[T<:Entity](a:T)
  def g(o:RefVal[Entity])= ???
  def g2(o:RefVal[_<:Entity])= ???
  g(RefVal[SEntity](a=SEntity())) // does not compile
  g2(RefVal[SEntity](a=SEntity())) // does compile

}
```

If I want to avoid making RefVal covariant then I need to use existentials here.

In other words, existentials are useful to set covariance in a more fine grained resolution, for example on the method level as shown above as opposed to globally setting RefVal covariant by declaring it as `RefVal[+T<:Entity]`.

EDIT2:

Here is some other useful usage of existentials:

```
object Existentials_List extends App {

  class A[T]

  class J

  class C1() extends J

  class C2() extends J

  class Z

  val l: Set[A[_ <: J]] = Set()

  val l2: Set[A[_ <: J]] = l + new A[J]   
  val l3: Set[A[_ <: J]] = l + new A[C1]   
  val l4: Set[A[_ <: J]] = l + new A[Z] // does not compile

}
```

Other possibility would have been to make  `class A[+T]` and just do `Set[A[J]]` but that can make a lot of things messy, the covariant + annotation can infect large part of the code where non of that covariant stuff matters at all. So keeping things invariant and using existentials at one place (in the collection where the objects are stored), might be a simpler solution than littering the code with covariance annotations.